# Reading using Keychain Wrapper class return Null - IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am using Keychainwrapper class downloaded from Apple documentation for storing login information like password. In my apps when user click on sign in button, I am storing in key chain like below...

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] 
                                     initWithIdentifier : @"vmo_login" accessGroup:nil];

[keychainItem setObject:email_id.text forKey:(__bridge NSString*)kSecAttrAccount];
[keychainItem setObject:password.text forKey:(__bridge NSString*)kSecValueData];
```

And if user click on sign out I am exiting application with exit(1). Once application is launched again, I am reading from keychain like below..

```
NSString *loc_email1 = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge NSString*)kSecAttrAccount];
NSString *loc_pwd1 = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge NSString*)kSecValueData];
```

I have not got what I have stored below, it returns NULL. Any Idea?.

thanks.

Comment: You should never ever call `exit(1)` this is not allowed by apple.

Comment: @rckoenes then how do I exit my application fully, I have an option in my apps signout and exit, How do I implement this?

Comment: You don't, Why the user will decide if he want's to exit the app by pressing the home button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem..

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] 
                                     initWithIdentifier : @"<need to give same as when we write>" accessGroup:nil];
```

Working fine now.